# Prove that $A∆B⊆C$ iff$ A∪C=B∪C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that  $A∆B⊆C$ iff $A∪C=B∪C$. I know that I am going to have to convert them to this form....
$AΔB⊆C$  is equivalent to $∀x:((x∈A∧x∉B)∨(x∉A∧x∈B))→x∈C$

and $A∪C=B∪C$ is equivalent to $∀x:(x∈A∨x∈C)↔(x∈B∨x∈C)$

How do I even go about proving this once I have written them out in set theory notation?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

To prove  $$A\triangle B\subseteq C\implies A\cup C=B\cup C$$ you don't need to rewrite it in set theory notation, just use the fact that $$A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$$ so $$(A\setminus B)\subseteq C$$ Observe that $$A=(A\setminus B)\cup (A\cap B)$$ since if $x\in A$ either it is also in $B$ and thus $x\in A\cap B$ or it isn't in $B$ in which case it is in $A\setminus B$ thus $$A\cup C=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)\cup C=(A\cap B)\cup C$$ by a nearly identical argument you can show that $$B\cup C=(A\cap B)\cup C$$ so $$A\cup C=B\cup C$$

For the other direction, let $$A\cup C= B\cup C$$ and assume to the contrary that $$A\setminus B\not\subseteq C$$ then there is some $x\in A$ but $x\not \in B$ and $x\not\in C$ so $x\not\in B\cup C$. This is a contradiction though since $$A\setminus B\subseteq A\cup C=B\cup C$$ thus $$A\setminus B\subseteq C$$ similarly, $$B\setminus A\subseteq C$$ so  $$A\triangle B\subseteq C$$

Comment: So I'm having trouble on the line after "thus" How would we conclude that A∪C is equal to the union of the elements in A but not B, the intersection of A and B, and  the set C based on the lines 4 and 6 (the definition of symmetric difference and the fact that (A∖B)⊆C?) This is my first real experience with set theory proofs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer by the way! Any help you can give is so much appreciated!

Comment: I will add some more details. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: And if you know, if you can add any details that would help me prove the converse? Or inverse? Not sure of the correct terminology but for instance, because it is an if and only if proof, I need to be able to prove A△B⊆C⟹A∪C=B∪C and I need to be able to prove A∪C=B∪C⟹A△B⊆C. You don't have to do the whole thing, but if you could give any tips for proving both ways, that would help so much!

Comment: @OliviaKat I added more detail. Let me know if there is anything else you don't understand.

Comment: SE318 thank you so much! I fully understand the proof now. Are there any specific laws or theorems that you used to prove this? The only reason I ask is because I will have to orally defend this proof in a course.

Comment: Not really. I used a few basic facts such as "if $A\cup B\subseteq C$ then $A\subseteq C$ but mostly it was using definitions.